# Sum of arrays element using direct addressing mode

Tags: assembly

A machine has only direct addressing mode meaning:

```
load R1, address    -->    fill R1 with value of Memory[address]
store R1, address   -->    fill Memory[address] with value of R1
```

some other instruction:

```
add R1, #immediate  -->    R1 = immediate + R1
add R1, address     -->    R1 = M[address] + R1
Loop R1, L          -->    if != 0 goto L
```

Comment: On some old computers like the CDC 3000 series, there were instructions to load or store a value from or to the address field of another instruction. This was a case where self modifying code was part of the  instruction set and worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without register-indirect addressing mode, there is no other way than **self-modifying code**, as already pointed out by rcgldr.

```
start:      load  R1, #arrayAddr     ; address of first array element
            load  R2, #arrayLength   ; loop counter
            load  R3, #0             ; sum

arrayLoop:  store R1, modifyAddr     ; modify operand of the instruction below
opcodeAddr: add   R3, dummyAddress   ; get array element, add to sum
            add   R1, #2             ; next address (assuming 16-bit integers, i.e. 2 bytes per element)
            add   R2, #-1            ; decrement counter
            loop  R2, arrayLoop
```

Define `modifyAddr` as the address of the instruction at label `opcodeAddr`:

```
modifyAddr = opcodeAddr + 1       ; (assuming instructions have a 1-byte opcode)
```

I used 3 registers. If the instruction set would include a 'compare' instruction, then 2 registers would be enough.